# Omit password field while retrieving User entity

Tags: security, jpa, passwords, spring-data-jpa

I've a `User` entity.

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    /* Other user attributes */
    /* Getters and Setters */
}r
```

I need to send this user to view layer to display user info but I don't want `password` field to be sent to view layer for security concerns.

Currenlty, I am not using DTOs.

**How can I omit `password` field while retrieving `User` entity from database?**

**Basically, how can I filter `password` field from `User` entity while sending to view layer?**

My application is built with `spring-data-jpa` and `spring-mvc`.

Comment: Well . . . your first problem is that you're storing the password.  That's an issue right off the bat.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How else can it be done? Can you provide some guidance?

Comment: This question is a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords
(yes, it's php, no, it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use JPA-Projections [Example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-basic-projections) . Spring may have similar feature..